# Proof of Horrocks splitting criterion - the book by Okonek etc.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In the proof of Horrocks splitting criterion, Theorem 2.3.1, Okonek, Schneider, Spindler, there is this situation:

$E$ and $F$ are vector bundles on Projective space $P^n$ of the same rank and same $c_1$. We have a morphism $\phi:F\rightarrow E$, which is an isomorphism on a hyperplane, i.e. $\phi|_H:F|_H\rightarrow E|_H$. This gives $$det\,\phi:det\,F\rightarrow det\,E.$$

Since they have the same $c_1$, $det\,\phi\in H^0(P^n,det\,F^*\otimes det\,E)\simeq H^0(P^n,O)$.

Since $det\,\phi$ is non-zero on $H$ and is constant on $P^n$, $det\, \phi$ is nowhere vanishing.

They say that : thus $\phi$ is an isomorphism. How does this prove that $\phi$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: In the end this should just be linear algebra, right? A map $A^n \to A^n$ with determinant a unit in $A$ is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the standard formula for the inverse matrix and apply it to the morphism of vector bundles. Explicitly, it works as follows.

Assume the rank of the bundles is $r$. First, consider the $(r-1)$-st exterior power of the map:
$$
\Lambda^{r-1}\phi : \Lambda^{r-1}F \to \Lambda^{r-1}E.
$$
Then transpose it:
$$
\Lambda^{r-1}\phi^T : \Lambda^{r-1}E^\vee \to \Lambda^{r-1}F^\vee.
$$
Finally, using the natural identifications
$$
E \cong \det E \otimes \Lambda^{r-1} E^\vee,
\qquad
F \cong \det F \otimes \Lambda^{r-1} F^\vee,
$$
and the isomorphism of determinants, one deduce from this the map
$$
(\det \phi)^{-1} \otimes \Lambda^{r-1}\phi^T : E \to F.
$$
This is the inverse of $\phi$ (that can be checked by a local calculation).